# Run Bookmarklet/Javascript on Firefox startup

Tags: firefox, bookmarklet

As the title says, I want to run a piece of javascript whenever firefox starts.

My actual problem is that the firefox window always opens at 0,0 in the screen. I am on a debian system,
with dwm as my window manager. I can successfully change the size of new firefox windows (by passing
in the -geometry commandline options), but all attempts to coax it to remember its location have failed.

What works is the following bookmarklet:

```
javascript:window.moveTo (32, 32);
```

So now, my problem could be resolved if I could get this piece of javascript to run everytime firefox starts. I've tried putting it in `user.js` (without the 'javascript:'), but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download the userChrome.js extension
now, enter the following line into /chrome/userChrome.js

```
window.moveTo (32, 32);
```

and you're done

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you set it as your home page?

Comment: that works (and the deserving upvote given), but doing it this way means that I'll lose the ability to restore my session. See my own answer for a less hackish way, but as a quick and dirty solution, this was nice :)

Comment: looks like I cannot answer my own question for the next 3 hours, so till then here's the keyword: userChrome.js

Comment: @KnickerKicker, what does your homepage have to do with restoring a session?

Comment: @Synetech - the browser will be automatically repositioned only when the browser is set to open the home page by default when it runs. It is an mutually exclusive option: either I set firefox to open the home page, or restore the previous session.

Comment: Oh, so you’re using a built-in session restore function. Okay, I see. Have you considered using an extension instead (which would provide much more functionality)?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new home page (a HTML) and put it there, between `<script>` tags.